# Question on backfeeding generator

Tags: generator

I have a 50amp gillette generator 9000 watts. My question is if i put a adapter to go from NEMA 14-50P to L14-30R with a nema 30r back feeding through my dryer plug would that be safe running a 50 amp generator.

Yes i know back feedings laws and everything just hypothetically asking if using a 50 amp generator through a 30 amp wire and circuit

Comment: An unsafe thing doesn't become safe just because you want to do it.

Comment: What's the output voltage of this generator?  Single phase or dual phase?  At the very least, you'll need to put a 30 amp circuit breaker between the generator and the dryer plug, but even then I wouldn't consider it safe.

Comment: Its 9000 watt starting 8000 watt continuous. Single phase. Theres a breaker on the generator im sure. Im just wondering is the amps are safe.

Comment: Max Power Rating: 9000 Watts
Continuous Power Rating: 8000 Watts
Voltage: 120/240 Single-Phase
Frequency: 60 Hertz
Sound Level: 79 dB(A) at 7 Meters
Rated Amps: 66 Amps @ 120 Volts (Single Phase)
33 Amps @ 240 Volts (Single Phase)
Fuel Type: Gasoline
Auto Voltage Regulation: None
Portability Kit: Optional
Tank Size: 8 Gallons
Run Time (75% Load): 9 Hrs
Battery: None
Outlets: (4) NEMA 5-15R 120V GFCI
(1) NEMA L5-30R 30Amp
(1) NEMA L14-50R
Alternator: Brushless

Comment: Hypothetically, yes you could wire it up to make it work, but don't try it.  You'll be risking the lives of utility company workers if you don't do things exactly right every time you use it, or if you have a faulty circuit breaker.  You'll also risk a house fire if you aren't extremely careful about limiting your power use to what the dryer circuit can handle.  It's better to go without power than face those risks.

Comment: Tell me about the service panel in question. Is the main breaker in that panel or is it elsewhere?  Is it CH, BR, Homeline, QO, Siemens, Murray, GE?  Do you want to light up all the circuits or only certain ones?

Comment: You obviously have been putting thought into this, why hasn't the thought of putting a transfer switch in come into the mix?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question , yes it is unsafe. This design is dependent on a human to ensure the main breaker is in the off position when powering the panel from the generator.  Humans make mistakes. Mistakes like this can kill.